# Business Intelligence - analyzing events rather than aggregates? What's the right approach

Tags: sql-server, analytics, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I currently analyze our customer data and trends by a number of SQL queries; and the testing of a hypothesis can be time-expensive.

For instance, we have a table of our customer info and a table of our customer service calls, indexed by customer. I'd like to find out if a particular cohort of customers had more CS issues than another; and if there is any correlation between customer service calls and increased cancel rates.

I was looking into MS's BI studio, as we're running MSSQL 2008 already; but most of what I've read focuses on carefully constructed MDX cubes that aggregate numerical data; so in the above model, I'd have to build a cube of facts (number of CS calls and types) and then use the customer data as dimensions. Fair enough, but in the time it'd take me to do that, I could just write the query manually in TSQL.

My DB is small enough that the speed gains from a separate datamart aren't necessary -- what I'm looking for is a flexible way of looking at my data, by creating a Customer 'Object' and tying all sorts of data, actions and numerical values to them. And I'd rather have the data extracted from my existing tables rather than having to ETL to a separate table.

Ideally at some point, I'd be able to use Data Mining tools for predictive analysis, but right now I'm going after low hanging fruit -- do customers from this ad campaign cancel more than the other one; etc.

Am I barking up the wrong tree with SQL Analysis Services/MDX cubes? Or does what I'm talking about not exist easily to begin with? Any advice, directions to products, or insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on who you want to do the analysis. If you are the one who is going to do the analysis, you know SQL, and you understand the structure of your data, then there's no real benefit to doing extra work to simply change the structure of the data. You want to use BI tools when you want to make that data available to others who don't know SQL, and don't necessarily know the relationships between different tables of data that are out there. You're in essence adding an abstraction layer to hide all this complexity from them, but still allow them to do the analysis. Of course the side effect of the abstraction is that you end up adding some limitations, but the trade-off is that the information is available to more people.

Comment: Fantastic information. But what about when data isn't normalized well -- i.e. cancel information is in one table; sign up is in another. I end up writing fancy SQL to create a temp table with the information I want to 'mine'.. .is that the way to go then; or is then when the object model makes sense?

Comment: Well, then you start dealing with data warehousing issues. On the one hand you can directly perform your complicated queries directly on the source data, and know that your analysis is based on the most current data. Or alternatively, you can transform your data into a form more convenient for querying, mining and analysis, but understand that the trade-off is how current your data is. Everything is a trade-off, and there are solutions to all these challenges, you just have to determine what your priorities are.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the perspective. So in the case of data 'slicing' and aggregation, it sounds like keeping it in SQL is the way to go if I'm the data provider and user..?

Comment: I would say yes. Perhaps save yourself some time by saving regular queries as views.

Comment: Thanks! (Got any favorite books on data/customer analysis in this context?)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't intending to ignore you, just got distracted. No specific customer analysis books that I've looked at. More generic DW and BI books.

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time with SSAS/cubes.  Your dataset is small and the scope of your problem is narrow...so there's no need for you to build a cube.  Instead, you should give the [Excel Data Mining addin](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/data-mining-add-ins-HA010342915.aspx) a test-run.  It's pretty powerful and works well with small datasets.  It is the low-hanging fruit I believe you are looking for.  Plus, users feel comfortable using Excel.

SSAS is not necessary for creating data mining structures/models is only necessary if you want to automate the process.

Building a cube first only helps when you have a very large dataset.  Because of its speed, it will allow the data mining algorithms to run faster.  Even if you use SSAS to build a data minining strucutre/model(s), you still don't need a cube...you can build the structure/model(s) off of relational tables.

If you database tables are designed correctly

Comment: I wasn't able to find any books on 'data analysis' techniques in SQL; they all ended up being SSAS and cube books. (It sucks that the tool you mentioned is only available for Windows 32bit. Makes me wonder if they're going to support it long term.)

Comment: Either way, do you believe that SSAS is a waste of time, even for simplifying the data analysis process on my end? Just construct intermediate tables to 'bring together' all the data I want; and then run the queries myself...

Comment: Nice catch about the addin only being compatible with 32bit.  I'm not sure what that says about the future of the tool, but I'd say anyone serious about analysis is going to be using 64bit (for PowerPivot)...perhaps microsoft just hasn't gotten around to it?

.........Anyways, because the add-in is no longer an option for you, Analysis Services can be used to mine your data.  However, there's still no reason for you to build a cube...just create a Mining Structure and some models based on the relational tables in your data source and move forward with training/mining/predicting/clustering/etc

Comment: fyi, 64bit data-mining addin was just released http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29061